# Auto-Update Statics On/Off

Tags: deployment, administration, sql-server, best-practices

MS recommends disabling **auto-create statistics** on SP DBs ([ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh292622%28office.14%29.aspx)).

What about **auto-update statistics**?

Looking at our TFS installation, for the SP DBs, these two options are disabled for you when TFS is installed/configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint runs a daily timer job that updates the statistics for you for a number of databases. It also checks the health of your indexes.

You can find more information in the following article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262731(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Got it! Just to add to that only certain SP DBs should have these options set to off. They are: Configuration databases,
Content databases,
User Profile Service Application Profile databases,
User Profile Service Application Social databases,
Web Analytics Service Application Reporting databases,
Web Analytics Service Application Staging databases,
Word Automation Services databases,
WSS_Logging (ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2011/11/17/auto-update-statistics-and-auto-create-statistics-on-or-off-for-sharepoint-2010-databases.aspx)